# Height of Last row in a wpf grid control

Tags: wpf, grid, height

I have a grid like this

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="100"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="100"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="100"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="100"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="210" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="210"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="210"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

When I resize the Grid, I found that the actual height of the last row always remains 100, assuming there is no control inside. So the problem is even if the Grid height is, for example, 450 the actual height still remains 100 for the last row.

I know I can get the  height of last row by subtracting the heights of the other rows from the Grid actual height. But why is the actual height of the last row is not getting updated when the Grid is being resized?

Comment: I don't think `Auto` is what you want here. Try `*`?

Answer (score 1):

You are saying the last row should determine it's height based on the elements in it, but be no smaller than 100 pixels tall. If there are no elements in the last row, then it would normally be 0 pixels high without the MinHeight.

Sounds like you want to use:

```
<RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="100" />
```

for your last row.

Comment: the question was if you set the height to Auto then why acutal heigt does not get updated.

Comment: @user686730 - Because if there is no control, then it would normally have an ActualHeight of 0. Since you added a MinHeight of 100, then the ActualHeight will always be 100. If you add a control to that row, then the ActualHeight could be larger than 100, if the control needs to be taller than 100 pixels to display it's content.